# I want to resolve the difference between the message response by manual input and copy paste in Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I want the two results to be the same. Could anyone please give me a solution.
The result is different between sending messages manually and copying and pasting in Teams.

After creating a simple bot to determine whether it is an email address,
input message: testtest@test.com
↓
result:
Manual input: return message = "It is MailAddress"
Copy paste: return message = "It isn't MailAddress"

I wondered if the input type was different, but it was the same.
I thought that the regular expression was wrong, but I don't think it was the result of entering the same email address.

The source code is as follows:

```
        private async Task <DialogTurnResult> OneStepAsync (WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var check = IsMailAddress(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text);
            if (!check) {
                stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync (MessageFactory.Text ("It isn't MailAddress"), cancellationToken);
            } else {
                stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync (MessageFactory.Text ("It is MailAddress"), cancellationToken);
            }
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync (cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
```

```
        public static bool IsMailAddress (string address)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (address))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return Regex.IsMatch (
                address, @ "^ [A-Z0-9 ._% +-] + @ [A-Z0-9 .-] + \. [A-Z] {2,4} $",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you copy paste in Teams, it adds extra space to start and end of the text.

For example when I copy pasted "help". I got Activity.Text as below in my bot

[image]

You should **Trim** the input text before using it.

```
var check = IsMailAddress(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text?.Trim());
```

Comment: I've solved this method!
thank you very much!
It was helpful!

Comment: @stkhr, You are welcome. Can you please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The *idea* of copy paste works fine, but what often happens is that extra things get caught in the process. For instance, Microsoft includes into the clipboard the time and name of the original massage poster, so that a message "foo" can become,  when copied:

```
[7:34 AM] Megan Bowen
foo
```

Even if it doesn't have the name/time, and you remove it, you'll often end up with a line break in the message box, so instead of:

```
foo
```

You'll sometimes have:

```
[empty line]
foo
```

you can cater for all  of these patterns by updating your regex appropriately. The first example (time/name) will require a full pattern update. For the 2nd example (opening linebreak) you could either solve it with a .Trim() command or, since you're already using regex, you could also just update your pattern to remove "leading whitespace".

hope that helps